# EC2 automatic windows updates disabled by default on Windows Server 2008 R2 - why?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2

I spun up an Amazon virtual instance for Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition and when I went into Windows Updates in control panel, automatic updates were turned off.  I turned them on and checked for updates and it found security updates, so I'm assuming I took the correct action, but is there something I'm missing and they should be disabled?  Is there a reason why they start out disabled?

Comment: I don't have any specific knowledge but I'm assuming they're disabled by default in order to let the customer decide how they want to manage Windows Updates.

Comment: And I assume they’re disabled by default to minimize the load that customers cause when booting up a bunch of instances without ever actually connecting to and configuring them. Though if you want to launch a bunch of identical instances, having automatic updates enabled is one way for them to automatically diverge to different states just by being powered on, so that’s a point too.

Comment: I would also love to know how to enable them again.

Comment: Looks like you can enable them by running the `sconfig` command.

Answer (score 0):

AWS offers [System Patch Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html)

> AWS Systems Manager Patch Manager automates the process of patching managed instances with both security related and other types of updates. You can use Patch Manager to apply patches for both operating systems and applications. (On Windows Server, application support is limited to updates for Microsoft applications.) You can use Patch Manager to install Service Packs on Windows instances and perform minor version upgrades on Linux instances. You can patch fleets of Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances or your on-premises servers and virtual machines (VMs) by operating system type. This includes supported versions of Amazon Linux, Amazon Linux 2, CentOS, Debian Server, macOS, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES), Ubuntu Server, and Windows Server. You can scan instances to see only a report of missing patches, or you can scan and automatically install all missing patches.